# How to fix QuerySet' object has no attribute issue?

Tags: django

I need to create the new object or just update if already existing. I receive: QuerySet' object has no attribute "seat". Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

models:

```
class rows_and_seats(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movies, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    row = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.movie}' 

class Reservation(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movies, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seat = models.ManyToManyField(rows_and_seats)
    ordered = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), blank=True, null=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer.username}:{self.movie.title}:{self.ordered}'
```

views

```
@login_required
def buy_seats(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.session.get("seats"):
        seats = request.session.pop("seats")
        movie = Movies.objects.get(pk=pk)
        customer = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
        for s in seats:
            user_reserved_seats = rows_and_seats.objects.get(movie=movie, row=s[:1], number=int(s[2:]))

            reservation_check = Reservation.objects.filter(customer=customer, movie=movie)
            if reservation_check.exists():
                reservation_check.seat.add(user_reserved_seats)
            else:
                new_reservation = Reservation.objects.create(customer=customer, movie=movie)
                new_reservation.seat.add(user_reserved_seats)



        messages.success(request,"You have succesfully reserved the seats.")
        return redirect("home")
    return redirect("home")
```

My goal is to keep rows_and_seat in manyTomany in order to display only one reservation of user in admin panel, instead of the list of repeating itself titles.

Comment: `reservation_check` is a queryset, `Reservation.objects.filter(..` can return multiple `Reservation` objects.

Comment: @gdef_ changed to objects.get and now it returns that it does not have attribute exists() hmmm

Comment: `.get(` will return only one value not a queryset, or will raise an error if it doesn't find any match. Are you sure that only will return 0 or 1 result? Or is there a chance of having multiple `reservation_check`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value after the `exists()` check:

```
if reservation_check.exists():
    reservation_check.first().seat.add(user_reserved_seats)
else:
    new_reservation = Reservation.objects.create(customer=customer, movie=movie)
    new_reservation.seat.add(user_reserved_seats)
```

Maybe you can use something like [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
user_reserved_seats = rows_and_seats.objects.get(movie=movie, row=s[:1], number=int(s[2:]))
reservation, created = Reservation.objects.get_or_create(
    customer=customer, movie=movie,
)
reservation.seat.add(user_reserved_seats)
```

Also you might be looping over the seats too many times, maybe you can add all the seats in only one assignment.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks a lot :) I'm new in django and still making a lot of mistakes

Comment: No problem! Check my edit, maybe you can use something like `get_or_create` or `update_or_create`. Check the docs, django's documentation is really good.

Comment: Cool, works as a charm :) less code = better code ! Actually I have last, small question if u don't mind. When creating new reservation, the new info is also displayed in previous reservations in manyToMany. The proper data which should be there is highlited on gray, but still I would like to get rid of the rest of things.

Comment: Great! Sorry but I don't fully understand the new question, maybe you can create a new post with more data and example and I can take a look. Also, if you don't mind upvoting the answer it would be great! Thanks for accepting it as correct!